# Read XML-Stylesheet attribute in a XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to know if a XML file does have the href attribute from
< ?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="recibo.xsl"? >
to determine what kind of Invoice it is (in my XSLT file). I´ve spend quite the time searching but couldn´t find any information on it. Is it even possible to read/acces those attributes in a XSLT?

Comment: Which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use, in which environment? That construct is a processing instruction with name `xml-stylesheet` and a target that can be any content although it looks like a sequence of attributes. Depending on the XSLT processor you have support to read e.g. https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/functions/saxon/get-pseudo-attribute.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the processing instruction is easy enough: `string(/processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet'))`. But that won't parse out the "pseudo-attributes" (`type` and `href`) in its value. You have to do that yourself, unless your processor provides a vendor extension such as `saxon:get-pseudo-attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 you could try e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="stylesheet-href" as="xs:string?" select="parse-xml-fragment('&lt;pi ' || /processing-instruction('xml-stylesheet') || '/>')/pi/@href"/>
```

to read out the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction node and parse its target into attributes from which you extract the `href` pseudo attribute value.

Note that `document-uri(document(''))` might also give you the stylesheet URI of the XSLT run.

Comment: Re last para, `static-base-uri()` seems simpler and more reliable.